# Can I safely just "return" from my constructor if I have default values for my parameters?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties

I have a personal side project that is effectively a small "evolution simulator". This simulator has objects of type `Critter`.  The properties of a `Critter` all have default values, i.e.:

```
public Rules.Size Size { get; set; } = Rules.Size.Medium; //average size
```

The class has multiple constructors.   One of these constructors accepts two "parent" `Critter`s and determines if they can successfully create a new `Critter` of their species

```
 if (c1.Species != c2.Species) //compare guids
        throw new Exception("Cannot combine critters of type " + c1.Species.ToString() + " and  " + c2.Species.ToString());       

    //check to see if breeding happens. 
    var chance = c1.ChanceToReproduce + c2.ChanceToReproduce / 2;
    var reality = new Random().Next(0, 100) / 100;
    //if the random "rolls under", success
    if (chance > reality)
        return; // no result.  Is this a bad practice in a constructor?
```

The last bit is where I'm not sure if I'm starting a bad habit or not.  Normally, you can't return a value from a constructor, but I'm not.  I use that to get out of `void` methods often, but in a constructor, it leaves me wondering if I've made a mistake somewhere.   I do know, however, that it's valid code.  The goal here is to just not fill in the statistics of the `Critter` that never was.

The questions are:

1. If I use a default parameter for all of my properties, will
   returning from a constructor prematurely populate those properties with the
   default values, or will they return `null` as if they had no
   defaults?
2. Is there a particular reason I should *not* use `return` to escape a constructor like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize:

1. Returning early from a constructor is completely safe and will result in the fields having their default values.
2. There's no real reason for you to not use return to escape your constructor, as the alternative can often be a lot of messy if/else blocks that are more difficult to read.

If you want to learn more, you can visit [Microsoft's site about C# constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Answer (score 1):

Property or field initializers assign their values before (your code in) the constructor runs.

`return`ing after that point doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

C# guarantees all instance fields have default values before your constructor runs. The language allows you to `return` at any time in your constructor.

My rule is that it should not be possible for a constructor to return an instance in an invalid or incomplete state; if a default value (like `null`) is invalid, it should not be possible for your constructor to return before that field has been assigned a valid value.